# Sample example from django-celery not working in Django app

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am following this tutorial

http://celeryq.org/docs/django-celery/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html

I startd the celery with

`python manage.py celeryd`

Then i  made `tasks.py` in `myapp` folder with

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Then i put these in settings.py

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"
    CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "mysql://user1:password@localhost/ajfdfa_rabbitmq"

    BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
    BROKER_PORT = 5672
    BROKER_USER = "guest"
    BROKER_PASSWORD = "guest"
    BROKER_VHOST = "/"
```

Then i started the python shell with

`python manage.py shell`

Then i type

from myapp import tasks

It went ok

But when i type function name then i get error

```
add.delay(4, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'add' is not defined
```

What i am missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of the shell did you do this?

```
from myapp import tasks
```

If so, you need to call it like this:

```
tasks.add(4,4)
```

Or you will need to change the import to the following:

```
from myapp.tasks import add
add(4,4)
```